# passing PHP variable into form within another PHP variable -no return value

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I cannot get the below to pass my PHP variable $pid into a html form in my other variable $submission_boxes that then passes that value to another .php page to feed it to the db.

```
<?php
include_once("connect.php");
$query = $conn->query('SELECT posts.id AS post_id, posts.post_date, posts.post_content, posts.hell_value, posts.heaven_value, users.id AS user_id, users.username FROM posts INNER JOIN users ON posts.post_creator = users.id ORDER BY post_date DESC');

$submission_boxes = "";

if($query->rowCount()) {
while ($r = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $content = $r['post_content'];
    $post_date = $r['post_date'];
    $hell_value = $r['hell_value'];
    $heaven_value = $r['heaven_value'];
    $post_id = $r['post_id'];
    $user_id = $r['user_id'];


    $submission_boxes .= "<table class='cat_links' border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" style=\"width:75%;\">
    <tbody>
       <tr colspan=\"3\">
          <td colspan=\"5\" rowspan=\"1\">".$content." </td>
             </tr>
       <tr>
          <td colspan=\"5\"><hr></td>
             </tr>
       <tr>
          <td colspan=\"3\" rowspan=\"1\" width=\"531px\"></td>
          <td align=\"center\"><font color=\"#994B43\">" .$hell_value. "</font></td>
          <td align=\"center\"><font color=\"#EAC67A\">".$heaven_value."</font></td>
             </tr>
       <tr>
          <td valign=\"bottom\" colspan=\"2\" rowspan=\"1\">Posted by  ".$username." at ".$post_date."</td>
           <td valign=\"bottom\" align=\"middle\"> <font size=\"size:6\">View Comments</font></td>
           <td style=\"width:100px;height:53px;\" align=\"right\"><a id=\"vote_button\"><form action=\"voting_hell.php\" method=\"POST\">
   <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"pid\" value=\"<?php echo $post_id; ?>\" />
   <input type=\"image\" name=\"vote_click_hell\" src=\"hellstamp.png\"   alt=\"<p>Hell</p>\" style=\"width:100px;height:53px;\">
</form></a></td>
           <td style=\"width:100px;height:53px;\" valign=\"bottom\"  align=\"right\"><a id=\"vote_button\"><form action=\"voting_heaven.php\"  method=\"POST\">
  <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"pid\" value=\"<?php echo $post_id; ?>\" />

 <input type=\"image\" name=\"vote_click_heaven\" src=\"heavenstamp.png\" alt=\"<p>Heaven</p>\" style=\"width:100px;height:53px;\">
</form>
</a></td>
             </tr>
        </tbody></table>";


}
echo $submission_boxes;

} else {
echo "<p>There are no categories available yet.</p>";
 }
?>
```

### [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixD0G.png)

If I hardcode it with an existing value it works fine.
Also I am pretty sure the issue is on this page as I have used print_r on voting_heaven.php and it returns this:

```
Array
(
[pid] => 
[vote_click_heaven_x] => 41
[vote_click_heaven_y] => 21
)
```

How do I get the pid value to pass?

Comment: Pictures of code are useless. past the relevant code snippets here.

Comment: Please post code to the question body. We're not going to copy code from a screenshot. It adds more steps for the people you're asking help from. Make it simple for us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of code doesn't *do* anything:

```
$post_id;
```

It's just a variable.  It resolves to the value of that variable, but there's nothing there which actually does anything with that value.

Maybe you meant to `echo` that value to the page?:

```
echo $post_id;
```

---

**Edit:** I just noticed that all of that code is just a string.  So you're outputting this *literal string* to the page:

```
"<?php $post_id ?>"
```

The browser isn't going to know what to do with that, and will just not display it.  Take a look at the page source in your browser.  If you see PHP code, you've done something wrong.

Earlier in the string you concatenate a variable.  Just so the same thing here:

```
"...value=\"" . $post_id . "\"..."
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's passing through now successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Your php code in value element doesn't have a `echo` so it doesn't display the value

Try this Code:

```
value=\"<?php echo $post_id; ?>\"
```

**Edit:**

You dont need to use `<?php ?>` in the value element because your already in `<?php ?>` area code.

Try This:
`value=\"" . $post_id . "\"`

Comment: I have just tried that, still recieving no value :/

Comment: You dont need to use <?php ?> coz the code is already in <?php ?> Code `value=\"" . $post_id . "\"`